# XSL: Display value if similar in two different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

I am a beginner in XSLT. My content comes from TEI file.

```
<!-- language: XSLT -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
 <!ENTITY menu SYSTEM "corpus.xml"> 


]> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
<!-- delete extra blank lines -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <head/>
  <body>
   <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::taxonomy[2]/category[4]"/>
   </ul>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="taxonomy[2]/category[4]">
<!-- several other 'xsl:for-each' within <ul> before the following <ul> --> 
<!-- each verb related to a sub-category ('category/category') in TEI -->
<ul>
 <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::category/equiv[@n]">
  <li>
  <!-- @uri = @xml:id in TEI -->
    <xsl:variable name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@uri"/></xsl:variable>
    <a href="{$href}"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="./@*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' and local-name()='id']"/></a>:
   <!-- ### Problem starts here: find same value in element 'w' and element 'equiv' -->                            
   <xsl:for-each select="//w[@type='verb']">
   <!-- @xml:id in TEI -->
     <xsl:variable name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"/> </xsl:variable>
     <a href="{$href}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="./@*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' and local-name()='id']" /></a>
      <!-- look to first value of @ana of element 'w' = value of @xml:id of element 'equiv'  -->
         <xsl:if test="//w[@type='verb' and @ana[1]] = preceding::category/equiv/@*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' and local-name()='id']">
          <xsl:value-of select="//w[@type='verb'and @ana[1]]"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A section of my TEI-XML file:

```
<!-- language TEI-XML -->
<!-- XPATH: /teiCorpus/teiHeader[1]/encodingDesc[1]/classDecl[1]/taxonomy[2]/category[4]/category[9] -->
<category n="9" xml:id="verb.motion" ana="#verb.category #action">
 <catDesc>taxonomy: motion verbs</catDesc>
 <category n="1" xml:id="meeting" ana="#verb.motion"> 
  <catDesc>subcategory of motion's verb as a concept: meeting  
  </catDesc>
  <category ana="#transcription" xml:lang="uga">
   <equiv n="1" xml:id="qry"/>
  </category>
 </category>

<!-- section taht gave me trouble to find data in XSLT -->
<!-- XPATH /teiCorpus/text[1]/body[1]/div1[2]/div2[2]/div3[2]/div4[2]/lg[1]/l[1]/w[2] -->
<w type="verb" ana="#qry #yQTL" xml:id="ktu1-3_ii_l4b-5a_tqry">
```

For example:
If `category/equiv[@xml:id]` and `w[@type='verb' and @ana[1]]` = `'qry'` (always first value of @ana), display `"href"` of `@xml:id` of element `'w'`.

I have no problem with first `select="following-sibling::category/equiv[@n]"`. I have what I want. 
Unfortunately for `select="//w[@type='verb']"`, what I have tried doesn't work: instead of a similar "href" of an @xml:id, I have ALL "href" and first value of @ana.

Current result:

> qry: ktu1-3_ii_l3b-4a_klʾatklʾat tqry tmtḫṣ tḫtṣ tmḫṣ tṣmt ʿtkt šnst tġll tgrš tmġyn tštql šbʿt tṯʿr ṯʿr tmtḫṣn tʿn tḫtṣb tḥdy t[d]ġdd ktu1-3_ii_l4b-5a_tqryklʾat tqry tmtḫṣ tḫtṣ tmḫṣ tṣmt ʿtkt šnst tġll tgrš tmġyn tštql šbʿt tṯʿr ṯʿr tmtḫṣn tʿn tḫtṣb tḥdy t[d]ġdd

Instead of:

> qry: ktu1-3_ii_l4b-5a_tqry 'tqry', ktu1-4_ii_l10_qryt 'qryt'.

Maybe the problem comes from `<xsl:if>` which is not the good choice?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Please share the input XML and the desired output so that the XSLT code can be tweaked to fix the issue? Do share the XSLT version that you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I did it. I hope it is enough to look where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow your question, but if you are trying to get a `w` node with a specific value in the `ana` attribute, you might benefit from a key.

```
<xsl:key name="w" match="w" use="tokenize(@ana, ' ')" />
```

Then, if you are positioned on the `equiv` element, you would get the matching `w` node like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('w', concat('#', @xml:id))">
```

Comment: I have just added to `<xsl:key>`  `match="w[@type='verb']"` instead of `match="w"`.